# difference between -h <name> and -o <outputfile> options in cc (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, unix, solaris, sunstudio

I am building .so library and was wondering - what is the difference b/w -h  and -o  cc complier option (using the Sun Studio C++) ?

Aren't they are referring to the same thing - the name of the output file?

Comment: Good question - the docs say, "in general, the name after -h should be exactly the same as the one after –o". It might be of more interest if they said when you might want them to be different or what happens if you specify one without the other. I think a little experimentation is in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-o` is the name of the file that will be written to disk by the compiler

`-h` is the name that will be recorded in ELF binaries that link against this file.

One common use is to provide library minor version numbers.   For instance, if 
you're creating the shared library libfoo, you might do:

```
cc -o libfoo.so.1.0 -h libfoo.so.1 *.o
ln -s libfoo.so.1.0 libfoo.so.1
ln -s libfoo.so libfoo.so.1
```

Then if you compile your hello world app and link against it with

```
cc -o hello -lfoo
```

the elf binary for hello will record a `NEEDED` entry for `libfoo.so.1` (which you can
see by running `elfdump -d hello` ).

Then when you need to add new functions later, you could change the `-o` value to
`libfoo.so.1.1` but leave the -h at `libfoo.so.1` - all the programs you already built
with 1.0 still try to load `libfoo.so.1` at runtime, so continue to work without being
rebuilt, but you'll see via ls that it's 1.1.

This is also sometimes used when building libraries in the same directory they're
used at runtime, if you don't have a separate installation directory or install
via a packaging system.   To avoid crashing programs that are running when you
overwrite the library binary, and to avoid programs not being able to start when 
you're in the middle of building, some Makefiles will do:

```
cc -o libfoo.so.1.new -h libfoo.so.1 *.o
rm libfoo.so.1 ; mv libfoo.so.1.new libfoo.so.1
```

(Makefiles built by the old Imake makefile generator from X commonly do this.)

Answer (score 2):

They are referring to different names. Specifically, the `-o` option is the file's *actual* name - the one on the filesystem. The `-h` option sets the *internal* `DT_SONAME` in the final object file. This is the name by which the shared object is referenced internally by other modules. I believe it's the name that you also see when you run `ldd` on objects that link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The -o option will name the output file while the -h option will set an intrinsic name inside the library. This intrinsic name has precedence over the file name when used by the dynamic loader and allows it to use predefined rules to peek the right library.

You can see what intrinsic name was recorded into a given library with that command:

elfdump -d xxx.so | grep SONAME

Have a look here for details:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter4-97194.html